# Accuracy over different sample sizes from dataset

Tags: python, descriptive-statistics, scikit-learn, exploratory-data-analysis

What I'm trying to do is predict how much more data would help in a classification task.

So, what I'm doing is bootstrapping entries in my dataset to get a sample, with a specified size. Then, I fine-tune a KNN model on the sample, and compute it's accuracy. I do this multiple times for one specified size, storing the accuracies in a list, from which I can compute the mean accuracy as well as the standard deviation of accuracies. And then rinse-and-repeat, for a different specified number of samples.

After doing this for enough different sample sizes, I practically get a new dataset, which I can fit a line to and predict how much more data would help.

[image]
However, this new "Accuracy vs. Sample Size" dataset surprises me.
What I expected was that at small sample sizes, more data would help out a lot, but with bigger sample sizes, more data would help out less, I would also never expect more data to *harm* the accuracy.

But, for some reason, it follows some quadratic line, the accuracy of 20 instances is (around) the same as 160 instances, the accuracy increase gets bigger as the sample size increases, and the worst accuracy is 100 instances... It's also much bumpier than I expected (I know there will always be some randomness as I'm randomly sampling from the dataset, but I resampled up to 3500 times for each sample size, and when I looked at the distribution for the 3500 resamples, they basically formed a perfect normal distribution, which means it's converged to the real value, right?). Can anybody explain this behaviour?

Here's a minimal working example (in python):

```py
# Imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

def auto_knn(X, y):
    """
    Returns accuracy of KNN with fine-tuned 'n_neighbours', fitted on 'X' and 'y'.
    """
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
    min_range, max_range = 6, 9
    found_best = False
    while not found_best:
        knn_search = GridSearchCV(knn, [{
            "n_neighbors": list(range(min_range, max_range))
        }], cv=5, scoring="accuracy", return_train_score=True)
        knn_search.fit(X, y)
        if knn_search.best_params_["n_neighbors"] == min_range and min_range != 1:
            min_range, max_range = min_range-1, max_range-1
        elif knn_search.best_params_["n_neighbors"] == max_range-1:
            min_range, max_range = min_range+1, max_range+1
        else:
            found_best = True
    return knn_search.best_score_

def knn_scores_from_subsample(X, y, subsample_size, num_iters):
    """
    Samples 'X' and 'y' with replacement to get new dataset of specific size, then fine-tunes KNN and retrieves accuracy. Resamples and retrieves accuracy 'num_iters' times. Returns list of accuracies.
    """
    accuracys = []
    for i in range(num_iters):
        print("\r["+"".join(["=" for _ in range(round(i/num_iters*100))])+"".join([" " for _ in range(round(100-i/num_iters*100))])+"] - "+str(round((i/num_iters)*100, 1))+"%", end="")
        selected_indexes = np.random.randint(0, len(X)-1, (subsample_size,))
        accuracys.append(auto_knn(X.iloc[selected_indexes], y.iloc[selected_indexes]))
    return accuracys

import requests
from io import StringIO

# Here, I'm using the Heart Failure Dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/andrewmvd/heart-failure-clinical-data),
# I've already done feature engineering, selection and preparation, so I've uploaded the prepared dataset, 
# to easily retrieve here.
orig_url = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qvIkRx07Il-Mat86MSo_i8iu2YEn9rnO/view?usp=sharing'
file_id = orig_url.split('/')[-2]
dwn_url='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' + file_id
url = requests.get(dwn_url).text
csv_raw = StringIO(url)
data = pd.read_csv(csv_raw)
data = data.drop("Unnamed: 0", axis=1)
X = data.drop("DEATH_EVENT", axis=1)
y = data[["DEATH_EVENT"]]

# Generate 'accuracy' vs. 'specific sample size'
# NOTE: This can take a very long time, to generate the image (above), it took many hours.
scores_for_n = {}
for num_points in range(20, 300, 10):
    scores_for_n[num_points] = knn_scores_from_subsample(X, y, num_points, 3500) # This will resample (with replacement) the dataset 3500 different times (and compute the accuracy).
    print("\nFinished "+str(num_points)+" points. Got a mean accuracy of "+str(round(np.array(scores_for_n[num_points]).mean()*100, 3))+"% With a standard deviation of: "+str(round( np.array(scores_for_n[num_points]).std()*100 ,3))+"%")

# Plot 'accuracy' vs. 'specific sample size'
plt.scatter(data_points, accuracies)
plt.xlabel("Dataset Size")
plt.ylabel("Mean Accuracy")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sometimes referred to as estimating a "learning curve". However the code you have provided has several shortcomings, which I believe makes the results not so useful.

1. Hyperparameter estimation is done on the same set as the final performance evaluation. This not a valid estimate for performance on unseen data. The model may be overfitted to the test set. Must use a separate validation and test split.
2. The dataset reduction is on the whole dataset. This means that the different degrees of reduction have different test sets. With small datasets this will introduce variations in performance. Should instead have a fixed test set that are split from the whole dataset, and just reduce the amount of training data.

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll try out these changes and see the result.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the code and updated the answer to include the code. Is it what you recommended?

Comment: Well, I've done a full-scale simulation implementing what you recommended, and the results make a lot more sense now, thanks!

Comment: Thats great! Glad to be of help